# Get Comment elements inside a element from Xml in Java

Tags: java, xml, nodes

**`I have issue while parsing xml in jaxb, it removing the comment node.For that I have created a method where I am storing the xml tag and path in map and later after parsing xml in jaxb again placing and arranging with proper path for those comments.
Storing in map.
Then placing those comment by creating comment node and using node.insertBefore(createComment, refChild) method.
Suggest.I have issue while parsing xml in jaxb, it removing the comment node.For that I have created a method where I am storing the xml tag and path in map and later after parsing xml in jaxb again placing and arranging with proper path for those comments.
Storing in map.
Then placing those comment by creating comment node and using node.insertBefore(createComment, refChild) method.
Suggest. I have issue while parsing xml in jaxb, it removing the comment node.For that I have created a method where I am storing the xml tag and path in map and later after parsing xml in jaxb again placing and arranging with proper path for those comments.
Storing in map.
Then placing those comment by creating comment node and using node.insertBefore(createComment, refChild) method.

My Issue is that, after updating this xml file, it becoming like,

and commented line placing at 1st position and value at 2nd because of node.insertBefore() method.
Can anyone suggest how to overcome it and place that value in same position like before as soon as possible`**

```
private static void updateComments(final Document document, final Map<String, Comment> commentNodeMap,
      final Map<String, Node> elementNodeMap, final Map<Comment, Integer> commentIntMap) {
    Set<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(final String s1, final String s2) {
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
          return s1.length() - s2.length();
        }
        String[] split1 = s1.split(Constants.COMMENT_SEPARATOR);
        String[] split2 = s2.split(Constants.COMMENT_SEPARATOR);
        Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(split1[0]);
        Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(split2[0]);
        if (((i1 - i2) == 0) && !split1[1].equals(split2[1])) {
          return split1[1].compareTo(split2[1]);
        }
        return i1 - i2;
      }
    });
    keys.addAll(commentNodeMap.keySet());
    for (String exp : keys) {
      String[] split2 = exp.split(Constants.COMMENT_SEPARATOR);
      Node node = elementNodeMap.get(split2[1]);
      if (node != null) {
        Comment comment = commentNodeMap.get(exp);
        List<Node> updatedNList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
          updatedNList.add(node.getChildNodes().item(i));
        }
        Integer integer = commentIntMap.get(comment);
        if (integer != null) {
          Comment createComment = document.createComment(comment.getData());
          updatedNList.add(integer, createComment);
          if ((integer + 1) < updatedNList.size()) {
            Node refChild = updatedNList.get(integer + 1);
            node.insertBefore(createComment, refChild);
          }
          else {
            node.appendChild(createComment);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

`Xml Code before:`

```
<shipments>
      <shipment id="011">
        <department>XXXX<!--ProductXXXXX--></department>
      </shipment>   
 </shipments>
```

Xml Code After:

```
<shipments>
      <shipment id="011">
        <department><!--ProductXXXXX-->XXXX</department>
      </shipment>   
 </shipments>
```

`Thanks in advance`

Comment: Sounds as if JAXB is causing you  a lot of problems. Have you considered a non-JAXB approach?

Comment: @Kimbert.
There are a lot of xml data manipulation is there  so i need jaxb to convert into class and change those data. while using jaxb it's not considering the comment  line. for that before converting to class, used some code to store path and comment in a hashmap. after  data manipulation trying  to add those comment at particular path. it's happening but those data I can able to add in the 1st position not after value as  I shown in the example.

Comment: JAXB is one way to do that. But there are alternative approaches that might be a lot simpler for your scenario. Why not use the standard DOM parser, which probably would not mess about with the XML comments?